# How to use chrome.storage inside of Angular component

Tags: angular, typescript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-storage

I want to fetch data from chrome.storage inside of my Angular component, but I get an error.

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'sync')
    at KTableComponent.loadData (k-table.component.ts:16:20)
    at KTableComponent_Template_button_click_2_listener (k-table.component.html:2:18)
    at executeListenerWithErrorHandling (core.mjs:15776:16)
    at wrapListenerIn_markDirtyAndPreventDefault (core.mjs:15811:22)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (platform-browser.mjs:459:38)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:406:31)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.mjs:26363:33)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:405:60)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:178:47)
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:487:34)
```

Here is my component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-k-table',
  templateUrl: './k-table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./k-table.component.css']
})
export class KTableComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  loadData() {
    chrome.storage.sync.get({dataKey: []}, function (result) {
      // Do something
    });
  }

}
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: Did you have a look at [`ng2-chrome-storage`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-chrome-storage) plugin, perhaps this could be the one that you're looking for?

Comment: Common mistakes are 1) not adding `"storage"` to `"permissions"` in manifest.json, 2) not reloading the extension on chrome://extensions page after editing manifest.json, 3) opening your app html through http:// when developing instead of opening it properly through the browser UI for the extension, 4) injecting the code using `script` element into the web page.